# how can i use javascript in String in variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm ready to project 'office reservation'.
but i got problem.

i want to change this script to 'for' type.

```
$("#o_status2").html('${roomMain.get("02").getR_endDate()}');
$("#o_status3").html('${roomMain.get("03").getR_endDate()}');
$("#o_status4").html('${roomMain.get("04").getR_endDate()}');
$("#o_status5").html('${roomMain.get("05").getR_endDate()}');
$("#o_status6").html('${roomMain.get("06").getR_endDate()}');
$("#o_status7").html('${roomMain.get("07").getR_endDate()}');
$("#o_status8").html('${roomMain.get("08").getR_endDate()}');
$("#o_status9").html('${roomMain.get("09").getR_endDate()}');
$("#o_status10").html('${roomMain.get("10").getR_endDate()}');

for (i = 1; i < 11; i ++) {
    $("#o_status"i).html('${roomMain.get("' + i + '").getR_endDate()}');
}
```

Comment: You have some typos in your code. `$("#o_status"i)` should probably be `$("#o_status" + i)`. Also, you probably don't want single quotes around things like `'${roomMain.get("02").getR_endDate()}'`. Try backticks instead.

Comment: thanks, i changed $("#o_status" + i). and i tried already '${roomMain.get("01~10").getR_endDate()}'. i got all result each other. then how i do change 'for' type?

Comment: Thanks, amazing! I tried backtics. Success.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `'${roomMain.get("' + i + '").getR_endDate()}');` is meant to return some HTML string, then what you want to do is to actually execute the expression. For example:

```
for (i = 1; i < 11; i ++) {
  $("#o_status" + i).html(roomMain.get(i).getR_endDate());
}
```

Note that I'm also assuming the `get` function accepts a number.

Comment: That mean to return end-date like '2020-04-22'.
I try making 'office reservation'. 'get("01~10")' meant room-number and made 'map' type. '01~10' is getting made <span id="o_room + number">. The number made 1~10 each other and having value 01~10. If i change construct, i will try it.

Comment: I changed 'map'type -> 'list'type, and used backticks. Then success. Thanks